# append given variable in stream of cpp files using awk/sed by ignoring backslash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a variable in shell script which is as follows:

```
 var=file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp file4.cpp
```

I want to append this "`Folder/SubFolder/` " to every .cpp file. I use the following `sed` command that helps partially:

```
 echo $var | sed 's/^/'"$i"'\//g;s/\s/ '"$i"'\//g' 

 where $i  --> "Folder"  and sed adds extra "/" to it
```

This `sed` is able to append only "`Folder/`"  to the files.... I am unable to append "`Folder/SubFolder`" to every file.

How can I modify sed to do add "Folder/SubFolder/"  path to the files. Can I modify it somehow to ignore the backslash "/ " in the `$i` variable ( i.e. ignore the "/" in `Folder/SubFolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different delimiter for `sed` like `#`

Also you can combine the `s` command together to a single `sed`

Example

```
$ echo $var | sed -r 's#(^| )#\1folder/subfolder/#g'
folder/subfolder/file1.cpp folder/subfolder/file2.cpp folder/subfolder/file3.cpp folder/subfolder/file4.cpp
```

**OR**

If you want to use variables inside `sed`

```
$ re="folder/subfolder/"
$ echo $var | sed -r "s#(^| )#\1$re#g"
folder/subfolder/file1.cpp folder/subfolder/file2.cpp folder/subfolder/file3.cpp folder/subfolder/file4.cpp
```

Comment: I managed to use it. but not completely. I have "for" loop where it is like " for i in <folder list>   this folder list depends < Folder1 Folder2/SubFolder Folder3 ..>   How can I replace folder/subfolder with sometime like $i ??

Comment: @Pogo Sorry but i didnt get you. Could you edit your question to add relevant details to it?

Comment: It worked as you said. but I am missing spaces in files. Folder/subfolder/file1.cppFolder/SubFolder/file2.cpp....

Comment: Should include `\1` in replacement string. See the example in my answer. Hope it clear

Comment: okay. I missed the `\1` in ur other example, and it works for folder and subfolder but does not work for single folders who do not have subfolders. I get Folder1File1.cpp Folder1File2.cpp . I will edit the answer if not clear.

Comment: I add to add extra "/"  to the folder string used in for loop.. :- Folder1/  Folder2/ Folder3/SubFolder3/  to get it working. thanks though

Comment: @Pogo Glad to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try these codes in a script

```
var="file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp file4.cpp"
i="Folder/SubFolder/"
echo "$var"|sed "s#[^ ][[:alnum:]]*[^ ]\.#$i&#g"
```

output

```
Folder/SubFolder/file1.cpp Folder/SubFolder/file2.cpp Folder/SubFolder/file3.cpp Folder/SubFolder/file4.cpp
```

Comment: Note I add sed "................" in double quotes so that bash can substitute the variable "$var" into the expression.